# How to use if else loop in Dialogflow for showing results

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have Javascript code for Dialogflow doing project on Google Actions. For this code if answer is in database means it will answer otherwise it is exiting out of app. So, I want to use else loop for this code plz help me

```
    function handleCompanyDetails(agent){   
  const RegNo = agent.parameters.RegNo;
  var ref8 =  admin.database().ref().child("Table/");
  var query8 = ref8.orderByChild("RegNo").equalTo(RegNo);
 return query8.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {  
   snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

    if( !snapshot.exists() ){
      // There are no results, say so
      agent.add("There are no results for that account.");

    } else {
      // ... Do something with the data
         agent.add(`The student placed in  ` + child.val().CompanyName);
    }

  });

 });        
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *can* use a loop to show results, there are a few problems with how you've done to, and possibly even with what you're trying to return.

First - Dialogflow requires you to return a Promise from any function that makes an asynchronous call, such as a call to the Firebase database. You're currently using the callback method. You should switch to using `once()` that returns a Promise instead, so that might look something like this:

```
return query8.once("value")
  .then( snapshot => {
    // working with snapshot goes here
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.error(err);
    agent.add("There was a problem.");
  });
```

The second is how you work with `snapshot` itself. If you're expecting multiple results, you should be aware that you can only call `agent.add()` with a text message twice and one basic card. If you want multiple cards, you may want to use a [list](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#list) or carousel instead.

If you are expecting only one response indexed off the `RegNo`, which it looks like you may be, then you should just include that as part of the path and get the value of the snapshot. You wouldn't need a loop in this case.

**Update** based on updated code.

As you noted, you're not sending anything if there are no results, so the Action exits with an error.

The easiest way to do this is to use [`snapshot.exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#exists) to check if there are any results in the snapshot. If there aren't any, then you can return an error. That might look something like

```
return query8.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {  

    if( !snapshot.exists() ){
      // There are no results, say so
      agent.add("There are no results for that account.");

    } else {
      // ... Do something with the data
    }

  });
  // ...
```

If you *do* have results, you still have the issue that you may be sending back too many replies. You can only have one `agent.add()` with a message to be spoken (or two, at the most, but don't do that) and only one Card, unless you use a List or Carousel. So it would be better for you to build that message inside the loop.

Comment: I'm getting same error if i say, regno that was not listed in database, it says my ap is not responding and exiting out of app

Comment: I'm getting this error check this https://drive.google.com/file/d/12EfQNIbsH3r3pwPlV-t4g6tFaioDVnvY/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please update your question to add the latest code that you are using along with the text transcript of the error - providing a video makes it much more difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Still same error, If i say wrong Id it was exit out of app still same after updating the code

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code and any logging you may include.

Answer (score 0):

Use .then() while doing operations on snapshot. Because .once() only triggers one time so if data is available meaning.then() will be executed and you can exit it using .catch(). check the code below.

```
function handleCompanyDetails(agent){   
  const RegNo = agent.parameters.RegNo;
  var ref8 =  admin.database().ref().child("Table/");
  var query8 = ref8.orderByChild("RegNo").equalTo(RegNo);
  return query8.once("value")
     .then(function(snapshot) {  
          snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
              agent.add(`The student placed in  ` + child.val().CompanyName);
              agent.add(new Card({
                  title: ` Name:${child.val().Studentname}
                  Reg No: ${child.val().RegNo}
                  Offer Date: ${child.val().OfferDate} `, 
                  imageUrl: '',
                  text:  `Thanks for using \n  ${child.val().FirstName} `,
                  buttonText: '.com'
              })
           })
        })
     .catch( // throw some error)
    }
```

you can read more here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Code is working now, but if i say get details using reg no it fill fetch if i say wrong number the app is existing and not handling error

Comment: I'm not getting what you're trying to say. can you please explain in understandable words.

Comment: Check this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/12EfQNIbsH3r3pwPlV-t4g6tFaioDVnvY/view?usp=drivesdk